# jQuery Image Zoom not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this code from [ElevateWeb](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples). I tried the last method **Image Constrain** on that web. However, I tried to copy that and still it doesn't work on my end.

First of all, my coding would be like this for HTML

```
<img id="img_01" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png"
        data-zoom-image="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png"/>
    <div id="gal1">
        <a href="#" data-image="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png"
            data-zoom-image="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png">
        <img id="img_01" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png" /> </a>

        <a href="#" data-image="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png"
            data-zoom-image="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png">
        <img id="img_01" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png" /> </a>

        <a href="#" data-image="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png"
            data-zoom-image="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png">
        <img id="img_01" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png" /> </a>

        <a href="#" data-image="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png"
            data-zoom-image="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png">
        <img id="img_01" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/images/test.png" /> </a>
    </div>
```

And the scripts I have put something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#zoom_03").elevateZoom({
        constrainType:"height",
        constrainSize:274,
        zoomType: "lens",
        containLensZoom: true,
        gallery:'gallery_01',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        galleryActiveClass: "active"});

    $("#zoom_03").bind("click", function(e) {
        var ez = $('#zoom_03').data('elevateZoom');
        $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

And I also put to call jQuery Library:

```
<script src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/scripts/elevateZoom/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/scripts/elevateZoom/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>
```

Firstly, the images are working and showing on the website but why I can't zoom the images in like [ElevateWeb](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples)? Am I missing something?

Comment: Check your console? Is there any error?

Comment: you bind events on element with id zoom_03, but there is no element with id zoom_3 in your html. I took a look at ElevateWeb, and there seems to be lots of errors like this in the example codes.

Comment: Nah, it's working after I changed id in html to #zoom_3. Thanks for the hints. Ya the examples were wrong. @mondjunge